# Something does not work when minimizing a function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

So basically I am trying to minimizing a function. I use the command "FindMinimum" since "Minimize" just returns the input.

FindMinimum gives me the minimized potential and the value of the two variables that minimize it. But... then I tried to vary parameters which gave me a different minimum, but the two variables still took the same value, which makes no sense to me.

Since I am dealing with very large and small numbers I suspect Mathematica cannot handle it.

For instance,

```
FindMinimum[((0.1) x^(-3) + (1/50000000) x^(-4/3)  + (80000^2 E^(-200 \[Pi] y) \[Pi]^2   Sqrt[y])/ 3 x - (4000 \[Pi]  y E^(-100 \[Pi] y))/(x^2)) / (800000000 \[Pi]), {x, y}]
```

$$\Big(\frac{0.1}{x^3}  + \frac{1}{5 \times 10^6 x^{4/3}} + \frac{8 \times 10^{8} e^{-200 \pi y} \pi^2 \sqrt{y}}{3x} - \frac{4000 e^{-100 \pi y} \pi y}{x^2} \Big) \frac{1}{8 \times 10^8 \pi}$$

As can be seen, this function is dominated by the first term. The output is

```
{3.97887*10^-11, {x -> 1., y -> 1.}}]
```

However, if I tweak the first term, letting $0.1 \rightarrow 1$:
$$\Big( \frac{1}{x^3}  + \frac{1}{5 \times 10^6 x^{4/3}} + \frac{8 \times 10^{8} e^{-200 \pi y} \pi^2 \sqrt{y}}{3x} - \frac{4000 e^{-100 \pi y} \pi y}{x^2} \Big) \frac{1}{8 \times 10^8 \pi}$$

```
FindMinimum[((1) x^(-3) + (1/50000000) x^(-4/3)  + (80000^2 E^(-200 \[Pi] y) \[Pi]^2   Sqrt[y])/ 3 x - (4000 \[Pi]  y E^(-100 \[Pi] y))/(x^2)) / (800000000 \[Pi]), {x, y}]
```

now gives the output

```
{3.97887*10^-10, {x -> 1., y -> 1.}}
```

Notice that the value of the function changed but not x and y. Why is that? Are these numbers too hard for Mathematica to handle? If so, something I can do about it? I am a bit confused. My objective is to find x and y that minimizes the function.

Comment: From the documentation, FindMinimum "searches for a local minimum" and "Except when f and cons are both linear, the results found by FindMinimum may correspond only to local, but not global, minima." Further, machine precision will not generally give the best results.

Comment: I see the function is complicated so it could be that other minimas are found. Do you have any idea why Minimize just return the input?

Comment: Furthermore, I know approximately the values on x and y that minimizes the function. Is it possible to search for a minima close to those values of x and y?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_, y_, t_] := (t x^(-3) + (1/
       50000000) x^(-4/3) + (80000^2 E^(-200 π y) π^2 Sqrt[y])/
      3 x - (4000 π y E^(-100 π y))/(x^2))/(800000000 π)

FunctionDomain[f[x, y, t], {x, y}]

(* x > 0 && y >= 0 *)
```

Since you "know approximately the values on x and y that minimizes the function", add constraints and use [`NMinimize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMinimize.html). From documentation, "NMinimize always attempts to find a global minimum of f subject to the constraints given." However, that is not a guarantee that the global minimum is found, and certainly not if the constraints do not include the global minimum.

```
NMinimize[{f[x, y, 1/10], 0 < x < 2, 0 <= y < 2}, {x, y}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 20] // N

(* {4.98816*10^-12, {x -> 1.99805, y -> 1.29799}} *)

NMinimize[{f[x, y, 1], 0 < x < 2, 0 <= y < 2}, {x, y}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 20] // N

(* {4.97359*10^-11, {x -> 2., y -> 1.29799}} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Things get a bit better if you remove the multiplicative constant:

```
f[x_, y_, t_] := (t x^(-3) 
   + (1/50000000) x^(-4/3) 
   + (80000^2 E^(-200 \[Pi] y) \[Pi]^2 Sqrt[y])/3 x 
   - (4000 \[Pi] y E^(-100 \[Pi] y))/(x^2));
FindMinimum[f[x, y, .1], {x, y}]
  (* {2.40011*10^-19, {x -> 1.55095*10^8, y -> 1.}} *)
```

However note that

```
Limit[f[x, x, 1], x -> \[Infinity]]
(* 0 *)
```